# Kusto Query for Azure VM's OS installed on VM's on different Subscriptions

Tags: azure

I'm unable to run a Kusto query for Azure Virtual Machines for OS installed on Different subscriptions giving incorrect results with Subscription name , location and we have security tags, but used SubscriptionId it is  also giving wrong result. Please suggest to get the Kusto query to get the OS name  installed on different subscriptions in Virtual Machines. Please suggest correct query.

Comment: Which query are you using right now and how does the result look? Do have access to the subscription / is it in the same tenant?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have RBAC permissions to at least **read** the other subscriptions, this query will run across all your subscriptions to return OS Type.

```
Resources
| where type == 'microsoft.compute/virtualmachines'
| project name, properties.storageProfile.osDisk.osType, subscriptionId, location, tags
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Resources 
| where type == 'microsoft.compute/virtualmachines' 
| extend osName = tostring(properties.extended.instanceView.osName) 
| where osName contains '2008'
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**